# session timeout issue in angular 4 model popup

Tags: angular, typescript, session, session-timeout

I implemented session timeout if the application is idle then It should redirect to login page. but It does not work as expected when model window is opened.

```
  this.userIdle.onTimerStart().subscribe(count => console.log(count));   
  this.userIdle.onTimeout().subscribe((res) => {
  sessionStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
  this.navCtrl.navigate('/auth/login');
  setTimeout(() => {
      this.msgSvc.error('Your session has expired due to inactivity.');        
  }, 1000);
```

});

For example:

When model popup is opened and the system is idle for certain period, it navigates to login page but the model popup still opened and available at the top of login page.

Can some one help me to how to close model window if it redirects to login page by detecting system idle

Comment: Can you share details about modal ? are you using ionic?

Comment: using bsmodel @Naseer